# Login Endpoint returns 403 forbidding in post man but browser authentication works (Spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am trying to secure/authorize my endpoints with JWT. The token is to be generated after successful login. The problem is anytime I call the login endpoint http://localhost:8080/login and pass in the credentials, it returns a 403 response.
Here is my spring security configuration

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

   
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated()).httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
   

}
```

Here is my LoginController

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    
    public ResponseEntity<?> getToken(@RequestBody AccountCredentials credentials) {
        // Generate token and send it in the response 
        //Authorization
        // header
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken creds = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());
        Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(creds);
        String jwts = jwtService.getToken(auth.getName());

        return  ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + jwts).
        header(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, "Authorization").build();

    }
}
```

Here is my UserServiceImplementation

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user =
        repository.findByUsername(username);
        UserBuilder builder = null;
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            User currentUser = user.get();
            builder =
            org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.
            User.withUsername(username);
            builder.password(currentUser.getPassword());
            builder.roles(currentUser.getRole());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found.");
        }
        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

If I visit http://localhost:8080/api in the browser and authenticate, it works.

This is my postman request
[image]

I enabled debug, Here are the logs when the endpoint gets called.
[image]

I don't know what I am doing wrong, Kindly Help.

Comment: Who (do you think) calls/invokes `configure(Global)` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the csrf.disable() and other configurations from the **protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)** method to the **SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)** method.

**Explainaiton:**

The problem here is your SecurityConfig class. Since, your class is not extending the the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, **protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)** will not have any effect on your applicaiton. All the configuation are applied from the @Bean of **SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)** method.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below method from:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .cors()
    .and()
    .csrf()
    .disable()
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated();
}
```

To:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
  http
    .cors()
    .and()
    .csrf()
    .disable()
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .httpBasic()
    .and()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated();
}
```

You have to add `httpBasic()` to this method

Also you send the username and password from authorization tab in postman directly by selecting basic auth option. And try accessing any protected link.

[This will show how to select basic auth]

Answer (score 0):

replace this code with configure (HttpSecurity).

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll().and().httpBasic();

    }
```